# Configuring web application to connect to database

Tags: java, database, jboss, struts2, dao

I have java web application using **struts 2** and running on **JBoss server**. We don't use Spring. This application does not use any database right now. They have moved some hard coded data in the application to database and have asked me to start using the database. I'll have to connect to the database to start with.

I have two conditions that have to be met:

> I am told we can't reconfigure the server since it is read only (**which means I cannot create DataSource on the server[add *-ds.xml to server] - Does it have any other meaning ?**) -

(This leaves me with an option to use DriverManager. Is there a better way ?)

> .  They have told me to keep the database connection properties file out of the ear file and in the config directory. (**Does this mean that I have to place the config file somewhere inside the jboss server?** What does this mean ? Will this eventually make me to "reconfigure" the server ?)

How do I place the database connection properties file outside the EAR and still have my DAO layer access the configuration properties ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Placing properties files in a web application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053395/placing-properties-files-in-a-web-application)

Comment: If you are using JBoss, you should use JNDI for your database connections.