# Placing properties files in a web application

Tags: java, jboss, struts2, configuration-files

In a java web application using struts 2 and running in Jboss server I am asked to place the properties file outside the EAR and in the config file.

What does this mean ? If it's outside the EAR how will the server recognize the config file ? Should the config file lie somewhere in the server ?

I want to use the config file as though it is in the web app class path.

Comment: Read BalusC's answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161054/where-to-place-configuration-properties-files-in-a-jsp-servlet-web-application).